# jQuery how to find image upper element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="uploadimage" >
    <img src="test.png"  />
    <div class="form-inline" >
        <button type="button" class="fileupload"> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <input type="file" class="upload">
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnupload"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

in jQuery I have the following code:

```
 $(".fileupload input").change(function () {
            var input = this;

            // this works but I think there is a better way
            var image = $(this).closest('.form-inline').siblings('img');


        });
```

I already get the image element but Im sure the peformance of that is no good.

> Any clue if there is a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I would usually do like this:
You can add/generate id to the `img` element, and add a reference to in in the a [data attribute](https://api.jquery.com/data/) of the btn or any other item what has to refer to it. This is easy even if generating these elements in a loop.

HTML

```
<div class="uploadimage" >
    <img id="testimg1" src="test.png"  />
    <div class="form-inline" >
        <button type="button" class="fileupload" data-imgitem="testimg1"> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
            <input type="file" class="upload">
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btnupload"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".fileupload input").change(function () {
    var input = this
    var reference = $(this).data(imgitem); // get id
    var image = $('#' + reference); // get DOM element by id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you could do this,

One of the way is to find the container `div` in your case which contains relevant `img`

```
$(".fileupload input").change(function () {
       // this works but I think there is a better way
       var image = $(this).closest('.uploadimage').find('img');
});
```

For your concern of which way could be better,

1. `.siblings()` : If you refer the documentation here https://api.jquery.com/siblings/ , this method matches `all` the specified selector and creates a new elements. This method should be used according to me only when you are going to `manipulate` an element, like changing `css` and properties. Internally, ofcourse it might be triggering `find` to match / get the element.
2. `.closest()` : This https://api.jquery.com/closest/ will be better in your case as compare to `.sibilings()`. It will not create a new element also will find only required element you are trying to search in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to access both the bound element and it's descendants that match the selector. Here is an example of a delegated event that allows me to target different elements from the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) with [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
 $('.uploadimage').on('change', 'input', function(event) {
   console.log(event);
   var input = $(event.currentTarget);
   console.log(input);
   var input = $(event.target);
   console.log(input);
   var image = $(event.delegateTarget).find('img');
   console.log(image);
   var image = $(event.delegateTarget.firstElementChild);
   console.log(image);
 }).find('input').change();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploadimage" >
  <img src="test.png"  />
  <div class="form-inline" >
    <button type="button" class="fileupload"> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>
    <input type="file" class="upload">
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btnupload"> <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

> When the browser triggers an event or other JavaScript calls jQuery's
>   .trigger() method, jQuery passes the handler an Event object it can
>   use to analyze and change the status of the event. This object is a
>   normalized subset of data provided by the browser; the browser's
>   unmodified native event object is available in event.originalEvent.
>   For example, event.type contains the event name (e.g., "resize") and
>   event.target indicates the deepest (innermost) element where the event
>   occurred.
>
> When jQuery calls a handler, the this keyword is a reference to the
>   element where the event is being delivered; for directly bound events
>   this is the element where the event was attached and for delegated
>   events this is an element matching selector. (Note that this may not
>   be equal to event.target if the event has bubbled from a descendant
>   element.) To create a jQuery object from the element so that it can be
>   used with jQuery methods, use $( this ).